# exclude results which are fetched first in search result

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm working on a *property* project where user searches for *properties* in some locality.
After fetching the relevant results I would like to display some suggestive results which should not contain the results previous displayed.

Table schema is:

```
property table:

+-----+-------------+-----------+-------------+------+----------+
| id  | property    | amenities | description | city | locality |
+-----+-------------+-----------+-------------+------+----------+
| 1   | House/Villa |           | some desc   | cit1 | loc1     |
+-----+-------------+-----------+-------------+------+----------+
| 2   | Office      |   ....    | desc....    | cit1 | loc2     |
+-----+-------------+-----------+-------------+------+----------+
| 3   | House/Villa | .....     | desc....    | cit1 | loc3     |
+-----+-------------+-----------+-------------+------+----------+
```

I want, if the user searches for `House/Villa` in **city** `city1` and **locality** `loc1` then along with the available results I would like to suggest him for other properties in same city with other **locality**.
What would be the `SQL` query. I've to use it in `PHP`

Comment: I don't know much about `sql` queries except `insert`, `update` or `delete`

Comment: Do you want the same type of properties in different localities with same city in the result i.e. should `Office` be included in the result if search criteria is `property = 'House/Villa' AND city = 'city1' AND locality = 'loc1'`, please provide a sample result for the same condition ?

Comment: no. `office` will not be included

Answer (score 4, accepted):

let your first query is

```
select * from property where city="city1" and locality="loc1" and property ="House/Villa";
```

then 
your query for desired result should be

```
select * from property where  property ="House/Villa" and city="city1" and locality NOT IN(loc1);
```

In will be better if you are showing him result for multiple location in first time, and want to omit that then
you can pass an array by makin an comma separated string,

```
$notIn = implode(", ", array("loc1","loc2"));
```

so NOT IN will fetch result that would not include passed location.

Step to optimize this query.

1. select only required column, do not use *
2. use limit e.g:-`select * from property where  property ="House/Villa" and city="city1" and locality NOT IN(loc1) limit 0,30;`// this will fetch only top 30 result. you can set according to your way.
3. select filtered data by using proper queries and subqueries
4. Not In is slow for  large result b/c mysql first scan full table then apply Not IN, so you can go for NOT EXISTS() instead of NOT IN().

Comment: i think the suggestion query will take longer if number of result are high

Comment: you can reduce fetched no of result by using limit .and if this is a serious issue than you have to go for query. optimization.@MohammadFaisal

Comment: if I'm using `not exists($notIn)` where `$notIn` contains the `id`s of previous results, then I'm not getting suggestions.

Comment: you should not use it here b/c NOT EXISTS is used for subqueries.means if NOT IN contain subquery then it is better to use NOT EXISTS .plz check http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

For proper answer:

```
SELECT DISTINCT property, amenities, description, city, locality FROM property
WHERE property = 'House/Villa' AND city = 'city1' AND locality = 'loc1'
```

For suggestions use:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT property, amenities, description, city, locality FROM property
    WHERE property = 'House/Villa' AND city = 'city1' AND locality != 'loc1'
```

Comment: should I use `IN` or `NOT IN`?

Comment: If you want properties in same `city` then use `IN`

Answer (score 1):

```
$property = 'House/Villa';
$city = 'city1';
$locality = 'loc1';

$q = "SELECT * FROM property WHERE property = '" . $property . "'AND city = '" . $city . "'";

$stmt = pdoObject->prepare($q);
$stmt->execute() or die(print_r($stmt->errorInfo()));
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);
foreach($resukt as $res)
{
   if($res['locality'] == $locality)
    echo "your search result";
} 

foreach($resukt as $res)
{
   if($res['locality'] != $locality)
    echo "this is suggestion";
}
```

I assume you are using PDO.

Comment: It doesn't matter, you can use whatever you want, just execute the query with another PHP function and loop through the results.

Comment: No. Actually I've to display the proper matches first then after suggestions

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this with just one SQL query

```
$query = "SELECT *, IF(locality='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($locality) . "', 1, 0) as locality_match FROM property WHERE property = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($property) . "'AND city = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($city) . "' ORDER BY locality_match DESC";
```

This puts the locality if statement in an if statement as part of the select. So it doesn't limit the results but instead gives us a value to sort by, so the items that match the locality will be first and suggestions will be at the end.

I also added an escape function around each parameter, because you definitely want to sanitize any input from the user.

Comment: @David, good one, but is there any way to know how many of results are suggestions or actual results?

Comment: the if is just a simple function in SQL (I'm referencing MySQL for this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if). I'm basically then taking the value of the check and setting it to an item that is returned with the results (`locality_match`). I also order on that so the matches are first.

Comment: @AmirNoori to get a count is a bit tricky, since you can't just count the results returned. I would probably just loop on the results and count them until you reach one that has `locality_match == 0`. All up to that point are matches. All after would be suggestions.